# How can I develop in Go with IDE capabilities for large projects

Tags: golang, ide

I am trying to migrate from GoLand to Emacs as my primary IDE for working with Go. I've gone through the standard advice online: company-go, go-mode, lsp, all that stuff. It was hell, it took forever, and I have to say I'm disappointed.

Most of all, what I *need* to work is proper completion/ displaying of documentation. Either there is a whole other layer to configuring company-mode, or this just doesn't cut it. Take this generic example:

```
import (
  "<path/to/module/because/it/is/a/very/large/project>/logger"
  "fmt"
)
logger.|
```

"|" is where the cursor is now. I'd expect all the public functions in logger to be displayed the same way `fmt.|` shows them, but no. Whatever completion I can find and run simply doesn't go that far. And I should mention in some cases, which I haven't been able to properly identify, the `fmt.|` thing doesn't work either.

Similarly, if I have a type declaration:

```
type thingA struct {
  varB thingB
}

var varA thingA
varA = ...
varA.varB.|
```

this should offer me all the methods on type `thingB`, but it doesn't. I get no errors (unless you count the occasional

> The connected server(s) does not support method textDocument/...

which also only happens sometimes). It just doesn't do anything.

I can't properly look for usages of a function even after running `lsp`, probably because the function is declared and used in other files than the one I have open. No simple overview of struct fields. No real support for structured text like "" and () that appear as you type the opening brace or quote, and doesn't overwrite the closing one when you type it, unless you use paredit, which isn't very good for c-like languages in my experience.

I could go on, but you get the idea. I want to actually work professionally, with the tools that are necessary for managing a project of this size and not have to define every one of these things myself. I hope I'm not asking for more than Emacs is for, but I don't think I am. There's probably going to be a stupid little thing that I'm not doing that'll make everything work.

Comment: I used go for a while a long time ago.  I think you need a package called gocode so that the company completion system works.

Comment: I have gocode already. That's the problem. It definitely helps, but not really that much.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using the Language Server Protocol is that your editor does not need to know any of the details of the language you are editing. That is instead the job of the Language Server. The capabilities of that server matter a lot, because they determine how completion works and so on. You need to determine what language server you are using, what features it has, and which commands it does or does not support. It is likely that fixing your problem will not involve any Emacs configuration changes at all.

Incidentally, you should quote the whole error message rather than chopping it off in the middle of the command name.

Edit: if you don’t know what LSP server you are using, run `M-x lsp-describe-session` and it will tell you. `lsp-mode` also maintains a log in the `*lsp-log*` buffer; you might check it for error messages.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense that it wouldn't be Emacs's fault necessarily, but rather a server. The problem, possibly not quite well explained, is that all Emacs tutorials all give me such protocols that end in the described behaviour.

As for the error, that is also my mistake. I didn't chop it off, I only wrote the part that is consistent, since how it follows depends on the function I called. What Language Server Protocols would you recommend?

Comment: There is only one Language Server Protocol; it is the standard that all LSP clients and LSP servers use to communicate with each other. You need to figure out what LSP server you are running, and how to troubleshoot it.